# Viewing Domain values as dropdown list in data grid in arcgis javascript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, domains

I'm trying to view layer data in a data grid, everything is fine, but when the data contains domain values, its place stays empty, and does not view any data.

Can anyone can help how to view it or am I supposed to build the table manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to build the drop down manually.

When a featureclass contains a field to which the coded value domain is setup, in that case, you get only the index values, and not the description as the attribute value.

If you look at the `fields` object on the query response, you'll see that it contains the domain, and using that, manually you'll have to set up the values, and the drop down if you wish.